# Can You Flip a Stack with a Runtime of O(1)?

Tags: c, stack, big-o

I am building a program that uses a doubly linked list to build a stack. I am required to flip the stack, or reverse the order of it, with a runtime of O(1). For instance:

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

becomes

4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1

The fastest way I can think of uses O(N) as a runtime. By being required to use a runtime of O(1) all loops are out of the question, as they will all inevitably depend on the number of nodes in the stack.

Can anybody recommend a reasonable way to go about this problem?

Comment: Why not just store a direction flag? Then reversing it is just flipping the direction flag.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Rather than `->prev` and `->next` members, have `->link[2]`, and access it as `->link[direction]` and `->link[1-direction]`.

Comment: A “doubly linked” list can actually be implemented by storing in each list item a single `uintptr_t` that contains the bitwise XOR of the two nodes on either side of it. When traversing the list, if the previous node is `P` and the current node is `C`, the next node is `(struct ListItem *) ((uintptr_t) P ^ C->RecordedXOR)`, regardless of in which direction you are traversing the list. So this implementation has an O(1) flip time merely by swapping the head and tail records. No direction flag is needed, and no adjustment to the indexing of the pointers in the nodes is needed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: While an xor list is a nice data structure, it's weaker than a doubly linked list (you can't reach anywhere starting from just an item in the list) and it's a rather unwieldy and error-prone thing for a non-expert in C to use.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: But it has the advantage that it is much more fun, which clearly outweighs other considerations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just store a direction flag global to the list, and flip it to flip the direction of the list. Define your list node as something like:

```
struct node {
    struct node *link[2];
    bool *dir;
};
```

Each node's `dir` pointer should point to a single `bool` object shared by the whole list (e.g. in separate allocated memory). Then wherever you would normally access `p->next` or `p->prev`, instead access `p->link[*p->dir]` or `p->link[!*p->dir]`, respectively. Now you can flip the sense of prev and next for the whole list just by inverting the direction flag: `*p->dir = !*p->dir;`.

Note that there's a cost to storing a pointer in each node, and you can avoid this just by keeping the flag separately "out of band", but this limits you to accessing the list (at least with knowledge of current direction) only where you have that out-of-band information; you then can't do it starting just from a member of the list.

Comment: When you write `p->link[!*p->dir]` do you literally mean to type that? For instance, `cur->link[!*cur->dir]` assuming `struct node *cur;`?

Comment: ^^^above comment

Comment: Yes, literally that (the opposite of the current forward direction).

Comment: Is there any way you would recommend implementing the flip inside of a function? I have tried storing a global int for and when it is 0 `*p->dir = *p->dir;` and when it is 1 `p->dir  = !*p->dir;`. It seems to be having no effect, though.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a new struct pointing to the tail of the linked list with `prev` & `next` pointers switched (swapped) may help. This way, in fact, you do not even swap or move any data value but just look at the data stream with a different set of glasses.

edit: And yes, as @Marceeaax noted, you had to be keeping track of the `head` & `tail` pointers.

```
typedef struct OriginalStruct {
    SomeType value;
    ...
    OriginalStruct *prev;
    OriginalStruct *next;
} OriginalStruct;

typedef struct ReversedStruct {
    SomeType value;
    // all same but the last two switched / swapped
    ReversedStruct *next;
    ReversedStruct *prev;
} ReversedStruct;

...
int main() {
    OriginalStruct *orgnHead = NULL;
    OriginalStruct *orgnTail = NULL;
    OriginalStruct *orgnList = createList(&orgnHead, &orgnTail);

    ...
    ReversedStruct *rvsdList = orgnTail;

    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using head and tail pointers, it should be enough by swapping those pointers. That would be done in O(1).

Comment: As in swapping the direction you read, not actually re-writing pointers.

Comment: That in itself is not enough: the head pointer would go to the final element in the list, but the next element would end the list.

Comment: I don't believe this solution, by itself, is sufficient. If you swap the head and tail pointers, then the relative ordering of the next/prev links in the linked lists will point the wrong way and you'll need to keep track of an extra bit to know whether that's the case.

Comment: If the node has a 2-element array of pointers, for the next and the previous node, then it can be indexed by the direction flag, or by `!` the direction flag, to go the other way.

Comment: ...and you can also make the head and tail pointers be the elements of a 2-element array, indexed by the direction flag, or `!` the direction flag.